# Negative Lookahead Invalidated by extra numbers in string

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I am trying to write a regular expression in R that matches a certain string up to the point where a `.` occurs. I thought a negative lookahead might be the answer, but I am getting some false positives.

So in the following 9-item vector

```
vec <- c("mcq_q9", "mcq_q10", "mcq_q11", "mcq_q12",   "mcq_q1.factor", "mcq_q2.factor", "mcq_q10.factor", "mcq_q11.factor", "mcq_q12.factor")
```

The grep

```
grep("mcq_q[0-9]+(?!\\.)", vec, perl = T)
```

does its job for the first six elements in the vector, matching `"mcq_q11"` but *not*  `"mcq_q2.factor"`. Unfortunately though it *does* match the last 3 elements, when there are two numbers following the second `q`. Why does that second number kill off my negative lookahead?

Comment: Why is this tagged perl -- do you want a Perl regex? (Btw, it's a negative lookahead, not "_lookbehind_").

Comment: the second number kills off the negative lookahead because at the position just *before* the second number, the pattern has succeeded, including the lookahead, which only checks at that one position in between the two numbers (unless paired with a `.*`) . (technically the engine backtracked and the `[0-9]+` gave up a digit in order for the neg-lookahead to succeed)

Comment: @zdim I tagged perl because of the `perl=T` argument in the `grep` function, and because I got an automated message saying regex questions stand a better chance if you identify a language.

Comment: Yes the `perl=T` argument allows perl-style regexes to be used within the regex-related functions in R

Comment: I am leaving my (edited) Perl answer since it should apply to your example in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to capture until a dot then you should use this:

```
mcq_q[0-9]+(?![\d\.])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DPefGn/15)

Sample Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/Ow1iBJ) )

```
vec <- c("mcq_q9", "mcq_q10", "mcq_q11", "mcq_q12",   "mcq_q1.factor", "mcq_q2.factor", "mcq_q10.factor", "mcq_q11.factor", "mcq_q12.factor")
grep("mcq_q[0-9]+(?![\\d\\.])", vec, perl = T)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rizwan M Tuman, however turning this into a positive lookahead this seems to capture *only* the elements that I want to exclude (i.e. with the `.factor` suffix)

Comment: @llewmills then probably this is what you have wanted... please see the updated regex and link

Comment: Thank you @Rizwan M Tuman. I wish I could accept all the answers because they all worked and were ingenious. But yours was framed as a negative lookahead and within grep. These are only minor things, but, in the absence of strong reasons to distinguish one excellent answer from the other, I had to fall back on minutiae.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want your negative lookahead to scan the entire string first, ensuring it sees no "dot":

```
(?!.*\.)mcq_q[0-9]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/f5XxR2/2/

Comment: This is very clever @sweaver2112. I don't know an enormous amount about regex but I have never seen a lookahead put before the match in this way.

Comment: `mcq_q[0-9]+(?!.*\.)` on the end works too - sometimes it's clearer to put it at the beginning, perhaps not in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

We can use it without any lookaround to match zero or more characters that are not a `.` after the numbers (`[0-9]+`) till the end of the string (`$`)

```
grep("mcq_q[0-9]+[^.]*$", vec, value = TRUE)
#[1] "mcq_q9"  "mcq_q10" "mcq_q11" "mcq_q12"
```

Answer (score 1):

A negative lookahead is tricky nere, as explained in a comment.  But you don't need it

```
/mcq_q[0-9]+(?:$|[^.0-9])/
```

This requires that a string of digits is followed by either end-of-string or a non-[`.`,digit] character. So it will allow `mcq_q12a` etc. If your permissible strings may only end in numbers remove `|[^...]`, and then the non-capturing group `(?:...)` isn't needed either, for `/mcq_q[0-9]+$/`

Tested only in Perl as the question was tagged with it. It should be the same for your example in R.

Comment: "I am trying to write a regular expression in R that matches a certain string up to the point where a . occurs" doesn't that mean having . is a must ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman By discussion of output in OP they clearly do not want to match at all when there is a dot, so _not having_ a dot is "a must" (for a term to match). Thank you for the comment, I tricked myself at first by thinking that one needs to match up to an optional dot.